# BigQuery showing "Invalid Credential", even though the service account is an editor

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-iam

I am trying to access BigQuery from GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine). But even after repeated trial and error, it's showing `Invalid Credential`.

I checked the access logs. The user is `xxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`, which is enlisted as an editor of the BigQuery dataset I am trying to access.

But this same query succeeds with the project owner's credentials. I tried elevating the service account as an owner, but that didn't change the outcome either.

The screenshots are as follows:

[image: Role Descriptions]

[image: Query Error]

[image: Query Success]

Comment: Is the service account been previously deleted and recreated using the same account name? 
According to this [article](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#deleting_and_recreating_service_accounts), if a service account is deleted and recreated using the same name, unexpected results might occur. Instead, a new account name should be used.
If using a different service account name is impossible, try following the steps in the same article in order to properly recreate the service account.

Comment: I'll check and let you know

Comment: Can you use the same service account outside of GKE and see if you get the same error message (such as from a GCE VM or using service account impersonation)